# Magento2 - delete all products not in a category

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Is there a simple way of deleting all products that does not belong to any category in Magento2?

Comment: You need to do this by programming.

Comment: Not just a simple mysql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following script from root folder:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

try{

    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
    $appState = $obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $products = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
    $products
        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->load();

    if($products->getSize() > 0) {
        $orphanProducts = 0;
        foreach($products as $product) {
            $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
            if(count($categories) == 0) {
                ++$orphanProducts;
                echo "Product " . $product->getSku() . " has no category." . "<br/>";

                // Uncomment below code to delete product
                // $product->delete();
                // echo "Deleted product successfully: " . $product->getSku() . "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Deleted products: " . $orphanProducts;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Note:**
Uncomment code form script to delete product.

Comment: Thank you!  very useful, had about 8000 products without a category after a clean up, and would take forever to find those and delete manually.

Comment: @Michael - Happy to help. Keep helping :)